# Error al descargar documentos con Swagger en WebApi con .Net

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, webapi, swagger

Estoy teniendo problemas con **Swagger** cuando un controller de mi WebApi devuelve un documento.

Estoy usando la libreria `Xceed.Word.Net` para generar un archivo `docx` en un `MemoryStream`.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
var doc = Xceed.Words.NET.DocX.Create(ms, DocumentTypes.Document);
...
doc.Save();
```

Una vez generado, la respuesta del WebApi la monto de la siguiente manera:

```
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray()) };
result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = ms.Length;

result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/force-download");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = filename,
    Size = ms.Length,
    CreationDate = DateTimeOffset.Now
};
return result;
```

Despues, hago la peticion a mi api desde el navegador (operacion GET) y me devuelve el documento sin problemas, pero si la petición la hago usando Swagger (tengo la ultima version), al pinchar en el enlace que aparece para descargar y guardar el documento, no puedo abrirlo porque dice que esta corrupto.

He comparado el documento que se genera de ambas formas y el problema es la codificación a la hora de guardarlo; no se como lo hace Swagger o que codificación usa pero el contenido esta mal codificado y Word lanza un error diciendo que esta corrupto.

Alguien mas tiene el mismo problema? Sabeis si se puede solucionar incluyendo algo en la respuesta del WebApi?

Espero vuestra respuesta.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: ¿A nadie le ha pasado esto?

Comment: He encontrado en la pagina de github de Swagger que parece tener un bug para esto... ¿a alguien le ha funcionado con alguna versión en concreto? no me importaria bajar la libreria de version - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2132

Comment: Yo estoy teniendo el mismo problema desde hace ya algún tiempo. Desarrollé un API para generación de informes e instale **Swagger** para facilitar al usuario las llamadas (y aprobechar la documentación) pero los archivos daban errores siempre al descargarlos. ¿Se sabe si hay alguna forma de corregir este problema? Yo tambien detecte que el problema era la forma en la que **Swagger** guarda el documento, ya que no coincide la codificación y se corrompe.